# Django's IGNORABLE_404_ENDS ... what am I missing?

Tags: django

So I'm late to the party here, but I just came across IGNORABLE_404_STARTS and IGNORABLE_404_ENDS.  I'm trying to make use of this, but it isn't working for me.  For instance, I set:

```
IGNORABLE_404_ENDS = ('mail.pl', 'mailform.pl', 'mail.cgi', 'mailform.cgi','favicon.ico', '.php')
```

If I go to http://www.mysite.com/test/mail.cgi, I will still get the 404 error message emailed to the admin account.  Am I missing something here?  My reading of the docs led me to believe that this case wouldn't generate an email.

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Comment: Yeah, this is running via apache so that's the only way to load in new changes.

Answer (score 0):

Is that line of code copied directly from your project? I ask because `IGNORABLE_404_ENDS` requires a iterable object, so if you accidentally set it to:

```
IGNORABLE_404_ENDS = ('mail.cgi')
```

(or, in other words, a string, not a tuple -- note the lack of a common before the file parenthesis) then `IGNORABLE_404_ENDS` will actually be equivalent to:

```
IGNORABLE_404_ENDS = ('m', 'a', 'i', 'l', '.', 'c', 'g', 'i')
```

and thus won't work as expected.

I only bring this up because I've made this mistake before.

Comment: It actually isn't, I was hand typing that.  I am using an example right out of the docs though, will edit my post.